# Can a abstract generic parent class automatically get child (extending) type?

Tags: c#, class, generics, inheritance

In my c# project, I have two abstract generic parent classes which then have multiple child classes that inherit them.  The problem is that I am passing the child type to the parent generic, and its making for some silly looking class and method definitions.

Is there a way in the Generic parent classes to get the type of a class inheriting them?  So instead of having to pass type  in DTOBase, declare that  will be the type of the first child of DTOBase.

Parent Class Definitions

```
public abstract class DTOBase<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged, IMergeable<T>

public abstract class ModelBase<T,U> : INotifyPropertyChanged, ITrackable, IMergeable<U> 
    where T : DTOBase<T>
    where U : ModelBase<T,U>
```

Example Child Classes

```
 public class MenuGroup : DTOBase<MenuGroup>

public class MenuGroup : ModelBase<DTOs.MenuGroup, MenuGroup>
```

Comment: Why do you need the type of the inheriting class?

Comment: In the first example, DTOBase, I need the type of the inheriting class for the IMergeable interface definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, that sort of thing is reasonably common when you have a type relationship which can't easily be expressed any other way. I have something similar in my Protocol Buffers port:

```
public interface IMessage<TMessage, TBuilder> 
    : IMessage<TMessage>, IMessageLite<TMessage, TBuilder>
    where TMessage : IMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>
    where TBuilder : IBuilder<TMessage, TBuilder>
```

It's annoying and ugly, but it gets the job done. Sorry not to have better news for you.

Comment: Darn.  That is frustrating because I think the compiler should be able to figure out those type relationships at compile time without having to explicitly inform it.

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare: It's not a *compiler* problem - it's that the type system isn't rich enough to express the relationship.